# How to add visual components to visual studio? (WPF)

Tags: data-visualization, visual-studio

I need to add data visual components such as charts and gauges to my visual studio project. I'm looking to either create them from myself or add an open-source extensions to use already implemented visual components.

Can anyone suggest a way to create visual components or else suggest open source extensions? I heard that Microsoft blend can implement components, but I couldn't find a way to create visual components.

Comment: I thought that the free edition of MS VS didn’t allow adding 3rd party components?  If you are not married to C++ and would be happy to code OO Pascal then http://www.lazarus-ide.org/ might be with you. You can add your own components or those of otters - and there are thousands, for free. With a little effort, you can convert Delphi components(http://www.blaisepascal.eu/lazarus/Chapter7.pdf) , of which there are tens of thousands. Btw, I personally think that this question is better suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ than this site.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify the [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) tag, DevExpress has [Gauges](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Gauges/) and [Charts](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Charting/).

It costs ~900 USD per developer and there is no redistribution fee. But that might be worth it, depending on how long you'd need to create such a thing yourself.

It also comes with Icons, Ribbon, Data Grid, Trees, Maps and various other things which are typically useful too.

Answer (score 0):

[Essential Studio](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf) has several data visualization components including charts and gauges. It is available for free under the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) - Davis (Syncfusion)